# Find anything between value="something" PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to find characters/letters in between the quotes of value="" and after that, change it.

I know its possible to learn how to find "unknown data" with regex etc.

Comment: well, we are normal people from around the world. Can you please reword your question with some normal words? And we are not code creators here, please show what you've tried.

Comment: eh you guys got your peroid at the same time? it was ment as a little joke. Whatever :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);   
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$fullstring = "this is my [tag]dog[/tag]";
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, "[tag]", "[/tag]");

echo $parsed; // (result = dog)

$newstring = str_replace($parsed,"new phrase or whatever",$fullstring);

echo $newstring; // (result = this is my [tag]new phrase or whatever[/tag])
```